# angularjs service error [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: Factory

Tags: angularjs, service, factory

I am writing a Factory/Service for the first time and trying to get an image from a factory into controller but getting undefined when in the factory function for some reason.

Here is the fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/vijay_vadlamani/2qL2Lh5r/1/
Html:-

JS:-

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('imageFactory', function() {
return function contentImage($scope) {
    $scope.getImage = function(content) {
    return getContentImage(content);
};
```

};
});

```
angular.module(myApp).controller('getImageCtrl', ['$scope', 'imageFactory', function($scope, imageFactory) {
$scope.getListImage = function(content) {
    return imageFactory.getImage(content);
};
```

}]);

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare service like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.factory('imageFactory', function() 
{
  var service = 
  {
    getImage: function(content) 
    {
      return getContentImage(content);

    }
  };
  return service
});
```

and use it like this:

```
app.controller('getImageCtrl', ['$scope','imageFactory',function($scope, imageFactory) 
{
  $scope.getListImage = function(content) 
  {
    return imageFactory.getImage(content);

  };
}]);
```

Here's [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/3kTmysGwpcJcxiI5MqbR)

Comment: When I try this I am getting the service itself as undefined in debugger previously I was getting the service but the getImage function was undefined

Comment: @Vijay I've edited the answer and provide you some demo